# call sass mixins from sass functions

Tags: sass

I have a sass mixin that generates the selector name:

```
@mixin rocks($name){
  #{$name}-rocks {
    @content;
  }
}
```

called by invoking the mixin:

```
@include rocks(dave){
  color: red;
}
```

I'd like to create a custom function that calls this mixin for me, to shorten the syntax down to:

```
rocks(dave){
  color: red;
}
```

Is it possible to 1. call sass @functions outside of a selector? and 2. Invoke mixins from it? Something along the lines of:

```
@function rocks($name){
  @include @rocks($name)
}
```

I'd prefer custom sass functions over custom ruby functions if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, and no.  Functions in Sass can only return values, they cannot be used to create CSS.  That is what mixins are for:  create mixins to call other mixins.

Comment: I know custom functions written in Ruby can do this, compass has a few like "nest(...)". Wish it were possible with sass script functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
@function class($name) {
  @return $name;
}

@mixin className($classname) {
  .#{class($classname)} {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin concatinate($classname2) {
  &.#{class($classname2)} {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin parent($classname1) {
  .#{class($classname1)} & {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin withparent($classname1) {
  @at-root .#{class($classname1)}#{&} {
    @content;
  }
}

@include className(red) {
  color: red;

  @include className(check) {
    color: green;

    @include concatinate(bcd) {
      color: green2;

      ul {
        li {
          color: red;

          & {
            color: blue;
          }

          @include withparent(colorwe) {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }

      @include parent(efg) {
        color: green1;
      }
    }
  }


  @include className(blue) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you can choose selectors with mixin and functions in sass V3

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks for the feedback; but I only got this soln to call the selector name from mixins;  so

Answer (score 0):

@DonaldDuck thanks for the feedback. Personally I think that there is no need to call selectors through mixins, if someone try to do that it will be solved by these mixins used.

e.g.:

```
//call a class
@include className(one) { 
  properties..
}//o/p    .one { properties..}
//add another class with existing one
@include className(one) {
  @include concatinate(two) {
    @include className(three) {
      properties...
    }
  }
}//o/p   .one.two .three { properties...}
//add parent to hierarchy
@include className(one) {
  @include parent(two) {
    properties..
  }
}//o/p .two .one { properties..}
//add class with top of the hierarchy
@include className(one) {
  @include className(two) {
    @include withparent(three) {
      properties...
    }
  }
} o/p  .one.three .two { properties..}
```